# Federation Metadata.xml for custom STS

Tags: azure, sts-securitytokenservice, azure-web-roles, acs

I am trying to implement a Custom STS as a WebRole to be deployed onto Azure. The problem i have is that how do i generate or write the Federation Metadata.xml file for my Custom STS. if i write it myself can i get the custom reference id and how do i sign it?
Also as my STS is an Azure application ,so when i run it the Azure Emulator it has a URL like http://127.0.0.1:81/ ,so i would using this as the link in the Federation Metadata.xml file but afterwards when i publish the STS onto Azure as a production deployment it would have a URL like http://cloudSts.cloudapp.net so i would have to reflect these changes in my Federation Metadata.xml file,the question here is that after making these changes should i upgrade/publish the package again and then move it onto production or else i can simply upload the changed Federation Metadata.xml file onto ACS(where i have my Custom STS as an IP) and it would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post I wrote on how to generate federation metadata dynamically: http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2010/11/03/Generating-Federation-Metadata-Dynamically.aspx

There is a variable in there called 'host' that you would modify.  There are a couple ways to do it.  You could look at the host header in the HTTP request, but you have to account for when it's not there.  Or you could stick it into the role configuration.  That would allow you to update it without having to redeploy.

Comment: Steve, your blog post "Generating Federation Metadata Dynamically" isn't there anymore.  Anyway you can revive it?

Comment: Found a copy of Steve's blog here: https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2010/11/04/Generating-Federation-Metadata-Dynamically.aspx